# Why JWT token uses Base64 encoding but not UTF-8

Tags: json, utf-8, jwt, base64

[RFC 7515 Section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-3) mentions:

> In both serializations, the JWS Protected Header, JWS Payload, and JWS Signature are base64url encoded, since JSON lacks a way to directly represent arbitrary octet sequences.

Why JSON cannot be represented using octet sequences?

Comment: JSON cannot represent arbitrary octets, not JSON cannot be represented by octets…!

Comment: can you give an example which arbitrary octect is not represented by JSON.

Comment: @Loki You can't put arbitrary octets inside of a JSON field. There is simply no data type to handle that. The closest thing would be an array of numbers for each octet. Otherwise, you have to put a base64 (or other textually-encoded) value in a String field.

Answer (score 3):

JSON by definition is UTF-8, so there is no way to (usefully) represent a byte sequence which is not a valid UTF-8 character.

For example, you cannot encode the bytes \x80 \x80.

(You could set up mutual agreement on both sides for additional semantics beyond what JSON supports, and encode them like for example `\\x80\\x80`; but then your format is no longer strictly JSON. In this case, to actually encode as UTF-8, you'd have to spell out the UTF-8 encoding for U-0080 twice! And then base64 is just a better convention because it's more compact, and avoids any confusion between characters and bytes.)

Comment: I did not get - _you cannot encode the bytes \x80 \x80_. utf-8 encode value for \x80 is `\x5c\x78\x38\x30`. How Base64 and UTF-8 differ here ? can you give little more info please

Comment: Because that encodes the Unicode character U+0080, not the actual byte value. Again, you could agree on a convention that the recipient has to be aware of and implement, but then base64 is just a better convention because it avoids any confusion between bytes and character code points.